# DS or DC al coda how to tell go to 3 and 4 verses

Tags: theory, notation, musical-forms, repeats

I have a song in this format:

```
Verse 1
Verse 2
Chorus  has a 1st and 2nd ending
Verse 3
Verse 4
Chorus
```

I use repeat for V1 and V2  and then I go to Chorus easy enough.
Now I want to go to Verse 3 and Verse 4 then finish with the Chorus and a little ending.

I know using a DS or DC al Coda will get me to the Beginning of song.
How do I tell go to Verse 3 and Verse 4 then chorus?

Do I place a note in the Chorus DC al coda to tell use Verse 3 and 4?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Dal Segno Al Coda.

The way this is used is:

1. Play until you reach the D.S. symbol
2. Go back to the 'S' (Segno) symbol
3. Play until the Coda symbol
4. Play the Coda.

Here are the symbols:

[image]

So, when the score reaches verse 4, put a D.S. Al coda symbol and the 'S' symbol on the beginning of the chorus.

At the end of the chorus put the Coda symbol and on the Coda put the ending of the chorus you want.